# Create / Write EXIF data using Magick.NET

Tags: c#, imagemagick, exif

Using ImageMagick-based library Magick.NET in C# to add EXIF metadata to a processed JPEG that does not currently have an EXIF profile. Attempts to create a profile have all failed:

```
 var newExifProfile = image.GetExifProfile();
 if (newExifProfile == null)
 {
    newExifProfile = new ExifProfile();
 }
 newExifProfile.SetValue(ExifTag.Copyright, "test");
```

`ExifProfile` has other constructors that accept a stream or byte array, not providing one creates an exception whenever `.SetValue()` is called:

> ```
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> at ImageMagick.ExifReader.GetBytes(UInt32 length)
> at ImageMagick.ExifReader.Read(Byte[] data)
> at ImageMagick.ExifProfile.SetValue(ExifTag tag, Object value)
> ```

**How can Magick.NET be used to write EXIF data?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have found a bug in Magick.NET and this has been fixed (https://magick.codeplex.com/workitem/1272). With the next release of Magick.NET (6.8.9.601) you will be able to do this:

```
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage("logo:"))
{
  profile = new ExifProfile();
  profile.SetValue(ExifTag.Copyright, "Dirk Lemstra");

  image.AddProfile(profile);

  image.Write("logo.withexif.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Hi, related question - is there a way to use more custom IPTC fields (numers from #220 to #240) with Magick.NET? Adding profile seems to remove any pre-existing IPTC records above #220 and press agencies often use more than 20 custom IPTC fields. Will it work if I manually format profile on ByteArray level?

Comment: Can you start an discussion here: https://magick.codeplex.com/discussions or here: https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/issues? I have some more questions. And can you create an example in your message?